# Keyword not supported 'data source' error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string

my connection string cannot login to my database.This is my connectionString

```
<add name="ProductEntities" connectionString="Data Source=**.**.***.**\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=product1_;User Id=product;Password=*****;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And these connectionStrings are that i tried in web.config

```
   connectionString="Data Source=**.***.**.**\MSSQLSERVER2017;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=product1_;User ID=product;Password=*****;"

 connectionString="data source=**.***.**.**\MSSQLSERVER2017;initial catalog=product1_;user id=product;password=*****;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and the other error is database cannot open.How can i fix this ?

Comment: `Server=...` will be correct.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy now it is says keyword not supported 'server'